# Express X as the sum of the the Nth power of unique natural numbers

Tags: scala, combinatorics, number-theory

I have recently been playing around on HackerRank in my down time, and am having some trouble solving this problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/functional-programming-the-sums-of-powers efficiently.

**Problem statement:** Given two integers *X* and *N*, find the number of ways to express `X` as a sum of powers of `N` of unique natural numbers.

**Example:** *X* = 10, *N* = 2

There is only one way get 10 using powers of *2* below 10, and that is `1^2 + 3^2`

**My Approach**

I know that there probably exists a nice, elegant recurrence for this problem; but unfortunately I couldn't find one, so I started thinking about other approaches. What I decided on what that I would gather a range of numbers from `[1,Z]` where *Z* is the largest number less than *X* when raised to the power of *N*. So for the example above, I only consider `[1,2,3]` because `4^2 > 10` and therefore can't be a part of (positive) numbers that sum to 10. After gathering this range of numbers I raised them all to the power *N* then found the permutations of all subsets of this list. So for `[1,2,3]` I found `[[1],[4],[9],[1,4],[1,9],[4,9],[1,4,9]]`, not a trivial series of operations for large initial ranges of numbers (my solution timed out on the final two hackerrank tests). The final step was to count the sublists that summed to *X*.

**Solution**

```
object Solution {
    def numberOfWays(X : Int, N : Int) : Int = {
        def candidates(num : Int) : List[List[Int]] = {
            if( Math.pow(num, N).toInt > X ) 
                List.range(1, num).map(
                    l => Math.pow(l, N).toInt
                ).toSet[Int].subsets.map(_.toList).toList
            else 
                candidates(num+1)
        }
        candidates(1).count(l => l.sum == X)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
       println(numberOfWays(readInt(),readInt()))
    }
}
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before? If so, are there more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 0):

After you build your list of squares you are left with what I would consider a kind of [Partition Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) called the [Subset Sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).  This is an old NP-Complete  problem.  So the answer to your first question is "Yes", and the answer to the second is given in the links.

Answer (score 0):

This can be thought of as a dynamic programming problem.  I still reason about Dynamic Programming problems imperatively, because that was how I was taught, but this can probably be made functional.

```
A.  Make an array A of length X with type parameter Integer.
B.  Iterate over i from 1 to Nth root of X.  For all i, set A[i^N - 1] = 1.
C.  Iterate over j from 0 until X.  In an inner loop, iterate over k from 0 to (X + 1) / 2.
    A[j] += A[k] * A[x - k]
D.  A[X - 1]
```

This can be made slightly more efficient by keeping track of which indices are non-trivial, but not that much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
def numberOfWays(X: Int, N: Int): Int = {

    def powerSumHelper(sum: Int, maximum: Int): Int = sum match {
      case x if x < 1 => 0
      case _ => {
        val limit = scala.math.min(maximum, scala.math.floor(scala.math.pow(sum, 1.0 / N)).toInt)
        (limit to 1 by -1).map(x => {
          val y = scala.math.pow(x, N).toInt
          if (y == sum) 1 else powerSumHelper(sum - y, x - 1)
        }).sum
      }
    }

    powerSumHelper(X, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
  }
```